# python program for accessing values from csv files and storing it into a database using wamp

Tags: python, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am new to Python and [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). I want to retrieve values from csv files (more than 10 GB) and, after some processing, store them in a MySQL database using Wamp efficiently.

I have installed Python and Django on Wamp server, and have checked the previous posts, but since I am a complete novice in this field, I am not getting much from them.

Can somebody please suggest appropriate resources for a beginner like me? I have already looked into [Python Power! The Comprehensive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598631586), but I did not get much from it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read data from CSV files using the built-in [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). For example:

```
>>> import csv
>>> open('test.csv','w').write('1,one\n2,two\n3,three\n')
>>> list(csv.reader(open('test.csv')))
[['1', 'one'], ['2', 'two'], ['3', 'three']]
```

You can write data to MySQL using the [`MySQL-python` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python), which conforms to the [Python database API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) and is [documented here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html). For example, after you've installed this package, you can do this kind of thing:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, passwd, db)
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO numbers (value, name) VALUES (%, %)',
...                    [['1', 'one'], ['2', 'two'], ['3', 'three']])
... 
>>> cursor.commit()
```

However, if you're using Django to manage the database, then you may be better off using Django's own database interface, for example [`Model.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) to save an instance of a model to the database.

Comment: Thanks but a very naive question, can I use MySQL-python package for files of 20GB and still have a fast processing.

Comment: Also please suggest some good books for learning about MySQL-python package